# Is there any way to monitor user's movement of iphone like the "raise to speak" feature?

Tags: ios, sensors, proximity, siri

I want to get notified when the user raises the iphone to his face. Just like siri does. Is it possible?

Add more specific requirement:
I want to darken the screen when user put the phone near his ear. I know the Proximity Sensor can be enable to implement this. But it's annoying that the screen will be darkened from time to time when user moves the finger upon the sensor. So I wonder how to avoid this case and only darken the screen when user raise the iphone to speak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Using the Proximity Sensor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW29) in the *UIDevice Class Reference.* So, you:

- Enable it:

  ```
  UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
  device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
  ```
- Check if successfully enabled; observe the [`UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW2) notification if successful; if not, your device may not be capable:

  ```
  if (device.proximityMonitoringEnabled)
  {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(handleProximityChange:)
                                                   name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification
                                                 object:nil];
  }
  else
  {
       // device not capable
  }
  ```
- And write your selector:

  ```
  - (void)handleProximityChange:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
      NSLog(@"%s proximityState=%d", __FUNCTION__, [[UIDevice currentDevice] proximityState]);
  }
  ```

---

To detect whether the user is holding it up to their face, I might marry the proximity sensor with the `CMMotionManager` and look at the `gravity` property to see if they're holding the phone nearly vertically. So, define a few class properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *deviceQueue;
```

And then you can start the `CMMotionManager`, looking for whether the device is held in a vertical position:

```
self.deviceQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 5.0 / 60.0;

UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
                                                        toQueue:self.deviceQueue
                                                    withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
{
    BOOL vertical = (motion.gravity.z > -0.4 && motion.gravity.z < 0.4 & motion.gravity.y < -0.7);
    if ((vertical && !device.proximityMonitoringEnabled) || (!vertical && device.proximityMonitoringEnabled))
    {
        device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = vertical;
    }
}];
```

Whether these `gravity` thresholds make sense is a little subjective. You could also, rather than just looking to see if the phone is being held roughly vertically, look at other accelerometer data (e.g. did they raise the object or not). Seems like there are lots of ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Presumably, the app has to be in the foreground for this to work?

Comment: @fantaxy You could use Core Motion to determine the orientation of the device. Or you could look at it's accelerometer data to figure out whether the phone was raised or not. Anyway, I've updated my answer with something that only does proximity monitoring if the phone is held in a roughly vertical position.

Comment: @mttrb yes, I presume that the app needs to be in the foreground.

Comment: @JitendraDeore I don't follow you. Are you asking how to just use the proximity sensor?

Comment: ya i used that code but my problem is when user move hand arond i want to get state or any value. please help me this...

Comment: @JitendraDeore You have to articulate what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, and explain, for example, why the proximity sensor approach doesn't work. That's going to be long enough that I'd suggest that you don't post that in a comment here, but rather post a brand new question, yourself. And, no offense, but simply saying you want to know "when user move hand" is not clear enough. That could mean anything. Tell us precisely what you want and why the proximity sensor (or whatever) was not sufficient.

Comment: @Rob i posted a new question in stackoverflow please check it out please help me.... to do that

Comment: Is there anyway to do this for apps running in background?

Comment: @nanospeck No, Apple only supports background operation in a fairly narrow set of circumstances (e.g. to let you finish some finite length task (not to exceed 3 minutes), or particular types of apps, such as navigation, audio player, VOIP, etc.). For more information, refer to the [App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I simplified the logic a bit and made a wrapper class in Swift.

[You can find it here](https://gist.github.com/miketsprague/1e4c075f82d1e03ce327)

```
class DeviceRaisedToEarListener: NSObject {
private let deviceQueue = NSOperationQueue()
private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
private var vertical: Bool = false

private(set) var isRaisedToEar: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != self.isRaisedToEar {
            self.stateChanged?(isRaisedToEar: self.isRaisedToEar)
        }
    }
}

var stateChanged:((isRaisedToEar: Bool)->())? = nil

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.setupMotionManager()
}

private func setupMotionManager() {
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 5.0 / 60.0
    let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()

    // Only listen for proximity changes if the device is held vertically
    self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.XArbitraryZVertical, toQueue: self.deviceQueue) { (motion, error) in
        self.vertical = (motion.gravity.z > -0.4 && motion.gravity.z < 0.4 && motion.gravity.y < -0.7)
    }
}

func startListening() {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = true
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleProximityChange:", name: UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

func stopListening() {
    UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func handleProximityChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.isRaisedToEar = UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityState && self.vertical
}

deinit {
    self.stopListening()
}
}


// How to use:
private func setupRaiseListener() {
    self.deviceListener.stateChanged = { [weak self] isRaisedToEar in
      println("is raised? \(isRaisedToEar)")
    }
    self.deviceListener.startListening()
}
```